# schema acceptance testing with meteor, velocity and jasmine

Tags: meteor, jasmine, integration-testing, velocity, meteor-collection2

A test to check that a schema defined validation requirement catches an invalid document on insert always fails with a message indicating a validation failure. The test is intended to pass if the invalid document is caught.

What is the appropriate way to construct this test?

Have considered venturing into package testing of Collection2 but am really not interested here in proving that package works. Rather I want to verify my schema is correctly built to pass the project requirements.

Context:

```
Windows 7
meteor@1.1.6
aldeed:autoform@5.4.0
aldeed:collection2@2.3.3
aldeed:simple-schema@1.3.3
velocity:core@0.9.3
sanjo:jasmine@0.16.4
```

Requirements:

```
1. Pulmonary Function test results (PFTs) are stored.
2. A pft document must contain a date (pftDate) and a Subject Id (subjId).
```

Schema:

```
PFTs = new Meteor.Collection('pfts');

Schema = {};
Schema.PFTs =  new SimpleSchema({
  subjId: {
    type: String,
    autoform: {
      type: "hidden",
      label: false,
    },
  },
  pftDate: {
    type: Date,
    label: 'Date',
    max: function(){ return new Date() },
  },
});

PFTs.attachSchema(Schema.PFTs);
```

Server Integration Tests:

```
"use strict";
describe("PFTs", function(){
  it("must be created with both subjId and pftDate set", function(){
    var testDate = new Date();
    var validNewPFT =   {pftDate: testDate, subjId: '1'}
    var invalidNewPFT = {};

    // Fails. 
    // No std Jasmine matcher seems to recognize that 
    // the validation has caught the invalid document.
    expect( PFTs.insert(invalidNewPFT) ).toThrow();

    // Passes.
    expect( PFTs.insert(validNewPFT) ).notToThrow();
  });
});
```

The Velocity test result:

```
Error: Subj is required
packages/aldeed:collection2/collection2.js:369:1: Error: Subj is required
  at getErrorObject (packages/aldeed:collection2/collection2.js:369:1)
  at [object Object].doValidate (packages/aldeed:collection2/collection2.js:352:1)
  at [object Object].Mongo.Collection. (anonymous function) [as insert] (packages/aldeed:collection2/collection2.js:154:1)
  at app\tests\jasmine\server\integration\pftDataModelSpec.js:8:18
```

Answer (score 1):

Discussion under an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2/issues/249) yielded the following solution:

```
"use strict";
describe("The PFT Schema", function(){

  it("contains keys for subjId and pftDate", function(){
  var schemaKeys = PFTs._c2._simpleSchema._firstLevelSchemaKeys;
  expect(schemaKeys).toContain('subjId');
  expect(schemaKeys).toContain('pftDate');
  });

  describe("context", function(){
    var ssPFTContext = Schema.PFTs.namedContext("pft");

    it("requires the presence of subjId & pftDate", function(){
      var validPFTData = {subjId: 1, pftDate: new Date()};
      expect( ssPFTContext.validate(validPFTData) ).toBeTrue;
    });

    it("fails if subjId is absent", function(){
      var invalidPFTData = {pftDate: new Date()};
      expect( ssPFTContext.validate(invalidPFTData) ).toBeFalse;
    });

    it("fails if pftDate is absent", function(){
      var invalidPFTData = {subjId: 1};
      expect( ssPFTContext.validate(invalidPFTData) ).toBeFalse;
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass a function to expect that you expect to throw:

```
expect(function () { PFTs.insert(invalidNewPFT); }).toThrow();

expect(function () { PFTs.insert(validNewPFT); }).not.toThrow();
```

As you can see it is `.not.toThrow()` instead of `notToThrow()`.

Comment: Thanks for the amazingly rapid response. It appears that this does not work. Collection.insert returns an id even if the insert fails. So I get back this message in Velocity:  
   
    TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ToThrow'

btw: I corrected the typo in notToThrow to .not.toThrow

Comment: Perhaps I should do the insert and then test that a document exists with the returned id. Seems a bit convoluted but given the return from collection.insert that may be the best way. I think there is probably nothing else to match on.

Comment: Nope.
`
"use strict";
describe("PFTs", function(){
  it("must be created with both subjId and pftDate set", function(){
    var testDate = new Date();
    var validNewPFT =   {pftDate: testDate, subjId: '1'}
    var invalidNewPFT = {};

    var invalidPftId = PFTs.insert(invalidNewPFT);
    expect( PFTs.findOne(invalidPftId) ).toBeUndefined();

    var validPftId = PFTs.insert(validNewPFT);
    expect( PFTs.findOne(validPftId) ).toBeDefined();
  });
});
`
Again get the original complaint: Error: Subj is required

Sorry for the formatting. mini-Markdown and I are not getting along.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting above. mini-Markdown and I are not getting along.

Answer (score 0):

@Sanjo Thanks for the guidance.

The following solves the question posed:

```
"use strict";
describe("PFTs", function(){
  it("cannot be created without a subjId", function(){
    var testDate = new Date();
    var invalidNewPFT =   {pftDate: testDate}
    var preinsertCount = PFTs.find().fetch().length;

    // expect used here to swallow the msg sent to the browser by Collection2
    expect( function(){ PFTs.insert(invalidNewPFT); }).toThrow;

    // Verify that a record was not saved
    expect( PFTs.find().fetch().length ).toEqual(preinsertCount);
  });
});
```

The first expect swallows the message sent to the browser by Collection2. Interestingly it does not matter whether .toThrow or .not.toThrow are used, the effect is the same. The real test is the check for an increase in the number of PFTs documents by one.